# Thymeleaf: On redirect from Spring-MVC controller, thymeleaf not reflect new values

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new in thymeleaf, thymeleaf template engine is really good, but i am face some critical problem with that, which is difficult to figure out for me. My flow is as below:

First call the add user controller and add the new user in database. After save the new user, redirect to user list page. When the user list page is open, my new user not display on user list. After refresh the page, my new user is visible. When i debug the code and check the user list controller. The user list controller fetch the new user detail , but my thymeleaf not display new changes. My thymeleaf cache is also false. I am using thymeleaf layout dialect as below:

https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect

My controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add-user", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEditCategory(User user, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    userService.saveNewUser(user);
    return "redirect:/user/userlist";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/userlist", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String productCategory(Model model, Pageable pageable) {

    Page<User> page = productCategoryService.findAllUsers(pageable);
    List<User> users= page.getContent();
    PageWrapper<ProductCategory> pageWrapper = new PageWrapper<User>(page, "/user/userlist");

    model.addAttribute("page", pageWrapper);
    model.addAttribute("users", categories);
    return "admin/user/view-users";
}
```

My Thymeleaf Configurations:

```
/* Thymeleaf configuration */
private ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);

    return templateResolver;
}

private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

private ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewClass(ThymeleafView.class);
    thymeleafViewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"user/**"});
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}
```

I am using `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` for register view resolver. The proble, is like cache problem. But how i resolve this?

**Update**

For adding user:- click on button and fancybox will appear. In fancy box i am using form and submit form on `/add-user` url.

**Update**

ContentNegotiatingViewResolver code:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver setupViewResolver(ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
    List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();

    resolvers.add(tilesViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(thymeleafViewResolver());
    resolvers.add(jspViewResolver());

    ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
    viewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your ContentNegotiatingViewResolver config

Comment: Also setCache false on your tiles view resolver

Comment: `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver ` have no option for `setChache(false)`

Comment: No tilesViewResolver

Answer (score 0):

To disable caching add -

```
thymeleafViewResolver.setCache(false);
```